# Scala Quill database - getting logging error

Tags: mysql, scala, logging, log4j, hikaricp

I am trying to use the scala library quill(http://getquill.io) for querying a mysql database but I get an error from Hikari where the logger can be created.

The error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\IdeaProjects\DatabaseTest\target\scala-2.11\classes;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\com.typesafe\config\bundles\config-1.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.8.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\mysql\mysql-connector-java\jars\mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\com.typesafe.scala-logging\scala-logging_2.11\jars\scala-logging_2.11-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\bundles\HikariCP-2.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\io.getquill\quill-core_2.11\jars\quill-core_2.11-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\io.getquill\quill-jdbc_2.11\jars\quill-jdbc_2.11-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\io.getquill\quill-sql_2.11\jars\quill-sql_2.11-0.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.javassist\javassist\bundles\javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.postgresql\postgresql\bundles\postgresql-9.4.1208.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-reflect\jars\scala-reflect-2.11.7.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.scalamacros\resetallattrs_2.11\jars\resetallattrs_2.11-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\log4j\log4j\bundles\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\jars\slf4j-api-1.7.19.jar;C:\Users\Freddie\.ivy2\cache\org.slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\jars\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.19.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.vogonjeltz.quilltest
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:550)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:172)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80)
    at io.getquill.JdbcSourceConfig.dataSource(JdbcSourceConfig.scala:22)
    at io.getquill.sources.jdbc.JdbcSource.<init>(JdbcSource.scala:34)
    at com.vogonjeltz.quilltest$$anon$1.<init>(quilltest.scala:11)
    at com.vogonjeltz.quilltest$.db$lzycompute(quilltest.scala:11)
    at com.vogonjeltz.quilltest$.db(quilltest.scala:11)
    at
```

This is the code:

```
package com.vogonjeltz
import io.getquill._
import io.getquill.naming.SnakeCase
import io.getquill.sources.sql.idiom.MySQLDialect

/**
  * Created by Freddie on 26/03/2016.
  */
object quilltest extends App {

  lazy val db = source(new JdbcSourceConfig[MySQLDialect, SnakeCase]("db"))

  case class User (auth_forename: String)

  val q = quote {
    query[User].filter(_.auth_forename == "Freddie")
  }
  println(db.run(q))

}
```

Comment: First, you should do as the error suggests, configure log4j logging.  But that is not your real error.  Your real error is that the pool cannot be initialized because of a misconfiguration.  Possibly an incorrect username/password, missing driver, etc.  You don't post the full exception so we can't tell.

Comment: Thanks! I got so hung up on the logger error, I didn't realise that I had an error in my config!